# Realm calculate and sort using subquery

Tags: ios, swift, realm

is there a way calculating and sorting using subquerys?

I have this objects(simplified) in my Realm database:

```
class Customer: RealmSwift.Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var name: String? = nil
}

class Order: RealmSwift.Object {
    @objc dynamic var id: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var customer_id: String? = nil
    @objc dynamic var region_id: String? = nil

    let total = RealmOptional<Float>()
}
```

Now I want to get only customers with orders in a region (using region_id) and sort the customers by calculating the total of all orders in that region.

Thanks,
Urkman

Comment: I don't understand, what relation is between `Customer` and `Order`?

Comment: In "Order" there is a "customer_id"...

Comment: Wouldn't be better to have relation many to many between `Customer` and `Order`?

Comment: Sure, I can update the database to have a `let orders = List<Order>()`. But, would that help me in this case?